# The query returned false

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm setting up a new function to store transaction data. The insert query ran successfully and the data was stored in MySQL, but my `index.php` caught a false query, so it didn't fetch the JSON.

I used `localhost` as server and `Postman` to test.

`index.php`:

```
$product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
$notes = $_POST['notes'];
$times = $_POST['times'];
$status = $_POST['status'];

$transaction = $db->createTransaction($product_id, $user_id, $notes, $times, $status);
if($transaction) {
    $response["error"] = FALSE;
    $response['invoice'] = $transaction['invoice'];
    $response['transaction']['product_id'] = $transaction['product_id'];
    $response['transaction']['user_id'] = $transaction['user_id'];
    $response['transaction']['notes'] = $transaction['notes'];
    $response['transaction']['times'] = $transaction['times'];
    $response['transaction']['status'] = $transaction['status'];
    $response['transaction']['created_at'] = $transaction['created_at'];
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // user failed to store
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Error in creating transaction!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

and these are my functions:

```
public function createTransaction($product_id, $user_id, $notes, $times, $status) {
    $uid = uniqid('', true);
    $invoice = "INV-".$uid;
    $date  = date("Y-m-d");
    $hour  = date("H");
    $time = date("i:s");

    $date = $date." ".$hour.":".$time;
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO transactions(invoice, product_id, user_id, notes, times, status, created_at) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $invoice, $product_id, $user_id, $notes, $times, $status, $date);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT invoice FROM transactions WHERE invoice = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $invoice);
        $stmt->execute();
        $transaction = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();
        return $transaction; 
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is what I expected:

```
{
    "error": false,
    "invoice": $invoice,
    "transaction": {
        "product_id": $product_id,
        "user_id": $user_id,
        "notes": $notes,
        "times": $times,
        "status": $status,
        "created_at": $created_at
    }
}
```

But it returned the following:

```
{
    "error": true,
    "error_msg": "Error in creating transaction!"
}
```

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: Whats the purpose of all this `$date  = date("Y-m-d");$hour  = date("H")$time = date("i:s");$date = $date." ".$hour.":".$time;`  surly you can do that with just `$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` - I don't see them used elsewhere so that is just unneeded complexity.

Comment: I still learn php from basic syntax, so I have not try that ORM yet

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix that one I use to change the format the date, I've simplified as you suggest and still error.

Comment: @FarhanMuhammad - sure I just point it out as it makes the code more convoluted and harder to read.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix thanks bro

Comment: It doesn't look too bad, I counted the fields and values and placeholders and looked for undefined Variables and it looks fine for those.  Could you have a unique index on that and try to insert a duplicate.  Do you have error reporting on?  I would look for SQL syntax error (fields named wrong) etc.  The `SELECT invoice FROM transactions WHERE invoice = ?` is not really necessary as you should have all that information on hand from the insert.  You just need to format it like a DB result and check that the insert was successful  Affected rows or such.

Comment: These 2 lines `$uid = uniqid('', true); $invoice = "INV-".$uid;` same as `$invoice = uniqid("INV-", true);`  That's like 12-15 lines I saved you...

Comment: I use that stuff to get the row, how should I write?

Comment: Nice one bro, thanks, I'm really beginner in php

Comment: When `$stmt->execute()` returns `FALSE`, you should print `$stmt->error` to get the reason.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix thanks man I've fixed this one, by adding the invoice lenght in mysql.